# Why don't my Toplink descriptors reflect the Java Code in the structure panel in JDeveloper?

Tags: java, jdeveloper, toplink

I am currently learning Oracle ADF, including the TopLink ORM. Well, I think TopLink is an ORM, correct me if I am wrong. I Added a connection to a sqlite database, and generated a bunch of Java class. I am using the [Chinook example database](https://chinookdatabase.codeplex.com/).

The wizard did not found foreign key mapping, so I tried adding one-to-many relationship between the `Artist` class and the `Album` class. I added a `List<Album>` field in the `Artist` class.

```
public class Artist implements Serializable {

    // Existing fields, default constructor and get/set omitted

    //...
    private List<Album> albums;

    public Artist(int artistid, String name, /* added this */ List<Album> albums) {
        this.artistId = artistid;
        this.name = name;
        this.albums = albums;
    }

    //...
    public List<Album> getAlbums() {
        return this.albums;
    }

    public void setAlbums(List<Album> albums) {
        this.albums = albums;
    }

}
```

I then tried to told TopLink that the album list had a one to many relationship with the Album elements. But when I opened the TopLink mapping and tried to edit the descriptor, my new field was not present in the "Structure" panel. I tried looking for a refresh button, but I found none. There was no "add field" either. I googled like crazy and did not found anything. Strange thing is, I restarted JDeveloper, and suddenly my `albums` field was there, and I was able to set a one-to-many relationship on it...

So really, my question is : is there a way to make the field appear without restarting JDeveloper? That could get old pretty fast.

Answer (score 0):

The problem disappeared after a few reboot. It was probably a bug in JDeveloper. The solution is the classic "three R" of computer troubleshooting.

1. Restart JDeveloper, so that the TopLink Structure panel reflect the Java Code
2. Reboot your computer.
3. Reinstall JDeveloper

Inconvenient... but it works.